# Passing Variables from context to another context

Tags: asterisk

so i need to use a variable from a context that a caller called to the context that the called party uses, so i have a code like this

```
[calledContext]

exten => s,1,goto(waits)
 same => n,goto(playmessage)
 same => n(waits),set(a=0)
 same => n(waits2),wait(5)
 same => n,GotoIf($[${a} = 0]?waits2:hang)
 same => n(playmessage),noop(${randomId})
 same => n(hang),hangup(); 

[callerContext]

exten => 012345,1,Noop()
 same => n,set(randomId=523)
 same => n,Dial(SIP/09201234567,20,G(calledContext^s^1)g)
 same => n,hangup()
```

heres my problem, in the calledContext context, when i use noop() on ${randomId}, nothing is displayed, how do i pass the value of the randomId from callerContext to calledContext?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SHARED is not what you want here.

The G option in [Dial](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Asterisk+13+Application_Dial) is one of those fun options that sends the two channels involved in the Dial operation to different places. Both are going to be sent to the Context/Extension you specified, which - given the names of the contexts - is probably not what you want. The called party gets sent to priority+1; the calling party priority.

That is, I'd expect the called party to start executing at calledContext,s,2 and the calling party to start executing at calledContext,s,1. But that's ancillary to your issue.

A variable set on an inbound channel can be passed to the channels it dials using [channel variable inheritance](https://wiki.asterisk.org/wiki/display/AST/Variable+Inheritance). That is:

```
exten => 012345,1,Noop()
; Using a single underbar will set randomId on all channels this
; channel creates, but will not continue to propagate further
same => n,set(_randomId=523)
; Using two underbars will cause the variable to always propagate
same => n,set(__someOtherId=111)
same => n,Dial(SIP/09201234567,20,G(calledContext^s^1)g)
same => n,hangup()
```

Using the _ or __ will cause the variables to be set on the called party. If you want the variables to continue to propagate to channels the called party may also call, then use __.

Answer (score -1):

Asterisk use concepts of CHANNEL or leg.

So in your call you have 2 channel, each one have independent variables and control structure

You can see name of bridged channels by BRIDGEPEER

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+Detailed+Variable+List

You can get variables of other channel by using function SHARED maybe.

http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+func+shared

For see variables set in current channel you can use application DumpChan

Comment: i tried SHARED(), it worked but dial() dials multiple numbers, each number has different randomId, and they are dialed all at the same time, so randomId got overwritten everytime, the passed randomId value is the last value assigned to it

Comment: I already give you hint. All other is your side programming. I not gooing do programming instead you,sorry.